# Is there a sage module to solve equation such as ax+by=c?

Tags: sage, diophantine

Is there a module in Sage to solve 2 unknowns in diophantine equations?
For instance, `ax+by=c` where `a,b,c` are known

I tried basic extended euclidean algorithm but my numbers are too large.

Comment: How large are your numbers? Can you share them? Were you at least able to check whether gcd(a, b) divides c?

Comment: Yes @SamuelLelièvre the gcd(a,b) =1

Comment: How did you run the extended gcd algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of solving diophantine equations in Sage are

- using the Smith normal form of matrices over ZZ
- using polytopes

See the answers to these two Ask Sage questions:

- [Ask Sage question 10364: Linear diophantine equations](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/10364/)
- [Ask Sage question 23666: Solving system of linear Diophantine equations](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/23666/)